# how to access to my browser in local machine from remote machine

Tags: ubuntu, browser, apache-spark, remote-access

because I run spark application on my remote machine and I want to see the progress so I need to access to spark web UI from a browser.

What should I do to be able to run my browser firefox on my local machine from the remote one in which I run my spark application?

If the distant (remote) one has an IP address:

```
192.yy.yy.yy
```

knowing that I use to access to remote machine from my local one

```
ssh name@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

ps: I can interact with the remote machine only using commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every SparkContext launches a web UI, by default on port 4040, that displays useful information about the application. This includes:

- A list of scheduler stages and tasks
- A summary of RDD sizes and memory usage
- Environmental information.
- Information about the running executors

You can access this interface by simply opening http://192.yy.yy.yy:4040 in a web browser. If multiple SparkContexts are running on the same host, they will bind to successive ports beginning with 4040 (4041, 4042, etc).

Source: [Monitoring Spark](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html)

Now that you have a management server in between, you need to create tunnel to access spark UI, to create tunnel use `ssh -L 4041:192.yy.yy.yy:4041 name@xx.xx.xx.xx` and then access spark UI through `localhost:4041`

Comment: which address ip should i use, because when i use 'ifconfig' i get  '192.yy.yy.yy'  and hen i use  'hostname -i i get completly other address  '10.xx.xx.xx ?

Comment: @hammad ip of your remote machine on which spark is running, you are connecting to remote machine by ssh name@xx.xx.xx.xx, so try xx.xx.xx.xx:4040

Comment: it 's a cluster, so i access by ssh name@xx.xx.xx.xx  to a node used only to manage the cluster(i can't launch spark on it) then i use 'ssh Node1' to launch spark and process, and Node1 has  'ifconfigip=192.yy.yy.yy'  and  'hostname -i-ip= '10.xx.xx.xx

Comment: this is what i get when i launch spark shell :Spark context Web UI available at http://10.xx.xx.xx:4041,  but it doesn't work too

Comment: ok, in that case you need to create tunnel, ssh -L 4041:192.yy.yy.yy:4041 name@xx.xx.xx.xx and then access spark UI through localhost:4041

Comment: is it possible to open more than one tunnel at the same time? for example one for 4040 and the other one for 8081??

Comment: yes, you can create more than one tunnel at a time, just use a new terminal window

Comment: @ shekhar i did try this before but when i ran the sparkUI for the master (8081), then i anted to see more detail about worker1 (its port 8085), i opened new terminal window, i used ssh -L 8085:192.yy.yy.yy:8085 name@xx.xx.xx.xx  then in my browser localhost 8085, it didn't work

Answer (score 2):

You only need to forward UI port from server to local

```
ssh -L 4040:localhost:4040 name@xx.xx.xx.xx
```

in local machine just go to address localhost:4040 to see the progress.

ref: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/115897/whats-ssh-port-forwarding-and-whats-the-difference-between-ssh-local-and-remot

Comment: that gives me an error saying connection failed:                                  open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused

Comment: which port are you running in your remote?

Comment: this is what i get when i launch spark shell :Spark context Web UI available at 10.xx.xx.xx:4041, but it doesn't work too

Comment: Before that you need to check whether spark UI is running yet by `netstat -apn | grep 4041`.
after that change to 4041 `ssh -L 4040:localhost:4041 name@xx.xx.xx.xx` and still access in local by localhost:4040.

Comment: in wich machine i write this netstat -apn | grep 4041?and this ssh -L 4040:localhost:4041 name@xx.xx.xx.xx

Comment: this is remote machine. Here you are forwarding your request of port 4040 from local machine to remote machine in port 4041 which are running Spark UI at the moment. So you need to make sure port 4041 in remote machine is working.
`ssh -L 4040:localhost:4041 name@xx.xx.xx.xx` -> type in your local machine.

Comment: @ giaosudau thank you very much, the solution was almost your idea

Comment: is it possible to open more than one tunnel at the same time? for example one for 4040 and the other one for 8081??