# Accessing google cloud internal dns from remote

Tags: browser, google-cloud-platform, dns, cloud

I am running pyspark on google cloud. The application launches a web ui from where you can monitor the performance of the app. I noticed that the web ui has the url of the internal google dns. with the -c-internal and the whole shebang. When i paste it into my browser on my local machine i see a server ip address not found message. Is there a way to access this webpage from my local or to access it in some gui way from the remote itself

Answer (score 0):

This already has an answer here which does what i want to do

[how to access to my browser in local machine from remote machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239214/how-to-access-to-my-browser-in-local-machine-from-remote-machine?rq=1)